# Enabling write-combining IO access in userspace

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, pci-e

I have a PCIe device with a userspace driver.  I'm writing commands to the device through a BAR, the commands are latency sensitive and amount of data is small (~64-bytes) so I don't want to use DMA.

If I remap the physical address of the BAR in the kernel using `ioremap_wc` and then write 64-bytes to the BAR *inside the kernel*, I can see that the 64-bytes are written as a single TLP over PCIe.  If I allow my userspace program to `mmap` the region with the `MAP_SHARED` flag and then write 64-bytes I see multiple TPLs on the PCIe bus, rather than a single transaction.

According to the kernel [PAT documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/pat.txt) I should be able to export write-combined pages through to userspace:

> Drivers wanting to export some pages to userspace do it by using mmap
>   interface and a combination of
>
> 1) `pgprot_noncached()`
>
> 2) `io_remap_pfn_range()` or `remap_pfn_range()` or `vm_insert_pfn()`
>
> With PAT support, a new API `pgprot_writecombine` is being added. So,
>   drivers can continue to use the above sequence, with either
>   `pgprot_noncached()` or `pgprot_writecombine()` in step 1, followed by
>   step 2.

Based on this documentation, the relevant kernel code from my mmap handler looks like this:

```
 vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_writecombine(vma->vm_page_prot);

 return io_remap_pfn_range(vma,
                           vma->vm_start,
                           info->mem[vma->vm_pgoff].addr >> PAGE_SHIFT,
                           vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start,
                           vma->vm_page_prot);
```

My PCIe device shows up in lspci with the BARs marked as prefetchable as expected:

> ```
>     Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
>     Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
>     Region 0: Memory at d8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
>     Region 2: Memory at d4000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64M]
> ```

When I call `mmap` from userspace I see a log message (having set debugpat kernel boot parameter):

> reserve_memtype added [mem 0xd4000000-0xd7ffffff], track write-combining, req write-combining, ret write-combining

I can also see in `/sys/kernel/debug/x86/pat_memtype_list` that a PAT entry looks correct and there are no overlapping regions:

```
write-combining @ 0xd4000000-0xd8000000
uncached-minus  @ 0xd8000000-0xda000000
```

I have also checked that there are no MTRR entries that would conflict with the PAT configuration.  As far as I can see, everything is set up correctly for write-combining to occur in userspace, however using a PCIe analyser to observe the transactions on the PCIe bus there the userspace access pattern is completely different to the same write performed from the kernel after an `ioremap_wc` call.

Why is write-combining not working as expected from userspace?

What can I do to debug further?

I'm currently running on a single socket 6-core i7-3930K.

Comment: What is the userspace visible address for the range?  Maybe it is not properly aligned?

Comment: @wallyk Good suggestion but the userspace visible address looks like it's aligned.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help, but this is how I got write-combining working on PCIe. Granted, it was in kernel space, but this complies with the Intel documentation. It's worth trying if you're stuck.

Globally defined:

```
unsigned int __attribute__ ((aligned(0x20))) srcArr[ARR_SIZE];
```

In your function:

```
int *pDestAddr

for (i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
    _mm_stream_si32(pDestAddr + i, pSrcAddr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this gives the same pattern of TLPs: Kernel space a single 64-byte TLP, userspace a stream of individual TLPs.