# Enabling write combining in Linux userspace app?

Tags: linux, caching

Is there a reasonable way for a Linux userspace program to enable/disable [cache write combining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_combining) for a memory page that it owns?

The two target systems I care about: Intel Haswell processor on a 3.0 kernel, and Intel Skylake processor on a 4.8 kernel.

I'm tuning a mature, multi-threaded application that uses large buffers to transfer data between a producer and a consumer.  Based on profiling, I have reason to believe that the application would benefit from the buffers' pages sometimes using write-combining caching, rather than write-back caching.

I considered instead using non-temporal writes to populate the buffer, but it would require a larger code refactoring than is possible for my current effort.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35862717/check-if-the-mapped-memory-supports-write-combining), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248444/enabling-write-combining-io-access-in-userspace), and [this LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/282250/) discuss the issue, but from the perspective of a device driver.  In my case, I'm working with userspace code, running as non-root.

[This 2008 paper](https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2008/ols2008v2-pages-135-144.pdf) discusses the different API's for controlling a page's caching mode.  It seems to indicate that a userspace application can obtain write-combining access to a page using `mmap` (see sections 5.3, 5.4 and 5.6), but the documentation isn't clear (to me, at least) regarding exactly how to use those mechanisms.

Comment: Sections 5.3 5.4 of https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2008/ols2008v2-pages-135-144.pdf are for access via `/proc` / `/sys` fs to PCI resources; 5.5 and 5.6 are for access to all computer memory with `/dev/mem`. Both requires root access and direct access to `/dev/mem` is unsafe. Try to use `non-temporal writes`, at least to compare is there any benefit to change write combining mode for code. Intel has hardware detectors of memory filling which may change combining mode, http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf 3.6.10 7.4.1

Comment: @osgx So user space PAT/MTRR programming is generally discouraged...?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar requirement recently where i needed to experiment with uncached memory in a cache-heavy multi-threaded application.

I came up with this [kernel module](https://github.com/lemonsqueeze/uncached_ram_lkm) which allows to map uncached memory in userspace. So it's a little different from what you're asking but maybe you can tweak it to achieve your goal.

Make it call:

- `set_memory_wc()` instead of `set_memory_uc()` and
- `pgprot_writecombine()` instead of `pgprot_uncached()`

and you should get write-combining memory.

At the moment you have to mmap() the module's character device (see `test` directory for demo) and memory type is fixed, but shouldn't be too hard to add an ioctl to toggle it.

I haven't tried changing attributes of existing userspace pages yet, would make it much nicer to use !